# Vue jest tests failing when expected to pass

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I am following a guide on Pluralsight where I am starting to learn how to Unit test in Vue and Jest. I am very new to both Vue and Jest. But these tests are very straight forward and should be passing when they are clearly not.

This is the HiChild Component that I need to test. It has a message property and a error variable that changes when the message property is longer or smaller than 3.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>The child says {{ message }}</h2>
    <div class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    error() {
      return this.message.trim().length < 3
        ? " The child can say bigger words than that!"
        : "";
    },
  },
};
```

Here are my Unit tests where I am testing the HiChild component. The first test try's to see if the message is properly inserted in the component. The second test checks if the error variable in the component is changed when the component is given a string that is longer and one that is shorter then 3.

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HiChild from '@/components/HiChild.vue';

describe('HiChild.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const message = 'hello there!';
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HiChild, {
      propsData: { message },
    });
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(message);
  });
});

describe('HiChild.vue', () => {
  it('renders error when message is too short', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HiChild, {
      propsData: { message: 'hi' },
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.error').exists()).toBe(true);

    wrapper.setProps({ message: 'good day to you!' });
    expect(wrapper.find('.error').exists()).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

This is the output of both tests:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The Component didn't have a `</script>` at the end.